# Dependency Injection in compile-time

Tags: dependency-injection

Why all DI frameworks check for all dependency in runtime before application start? Why not to check that in compile-time, what are benefits for that?

Is it possible to change dependency in deployed application?
For example when application started it sends notification through email, but after can we change to send through sms without stopping application?

Comment: You seem to have missed the point in using a DI framework... If you do it at compile time then you are just hard-wiring your dependancies, which is not DI...

Comment: Ok, so you can change dependency in already deployed application?

Comment: That is one point yes. It also allows you to conditionally register different implementations based on other information that only be known at run time... It also makes maintenance harder...

Comment: Ok, you can switch dependency without stopping application. What library for DI are you using? Can you please provide a link to an example how to switch dependency without stopping application in that library? Thanks.

Comment: ... You can just call the relevant method on your DI container, basically the same way you registered it in the first place..... although a better approach is to register instead a Factory, which returns the correct implementation based on some logic it performs at runtime... I tend to use the build in ASP.NET MVC DI container for MVC apps, although I have used Unity quite a lot as well in other projects. Try reading some tutorials: https://stevescodingblog.co.uk/dependency-injection-beginners-guide/

Comment: @Milney I think you miss the point of DI as well. DI is a set of _patterns and principles_ and it doesn't require a framework at all. You can easily apply DI by wiring your dependencies [by hand](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) in a [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

Comment: @Steven Then you are just writing your own (probably not very good) DI Framework...

Comment: @Steven My comment was against HARD-CODING the dependencies, which is not really DI, it is IoC (Inversion of Control), but not Injection

Comment: I'm really sorry @Milney, but your statements are false. Please read [this](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) closely. I advice against writing any code that resembles a DI Container (which uses some kind of dictionary and reflection). I advice to either use an existing DI Container -or- to use Pure DI.

Comment: @Steven Sure bro

Comment: @Milney, btw, there's coming a [2nd edition of the awesome book Dependency Injection in .NET](https://www.manning.com/books/dependency-injection-in-dot-net-second-edition). I can advise you to either read the first edition or you can read the second edition while it is being written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DI Containers by definition work by using reflection which means *runtime metadata*. If you want everything to be checked at compile-time, you should not use a DI Container. In that case there are other options.

When you require everything to be wired at compile time, you can either use a practice called [Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/), which means you hand-wire your dependencies in the application's [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) using the `new` keyword of your language.

The second option is to use a tool or process that uses a post-compilation process to generate these object graphs (the chain of classes that contain behavior with their dependencies) and their `new` keywords. From a definition's point of view, those tools are not 'DI Containers' because they don't depend on *runtime metadata*. What they offer is a code generation process, with a syntax that has some similarity to DI Containers, while their generated code is similar to that of Pure DI. Compared to DI Containers they are limited in flexibility, but they are useful in scenarios where reflection is too costly -or simply unavailable- or the application's constraints in memory usage prevents the use of a DI Container as runtime.

> but after can we change to send through sms without stopping application?

You seem to require the application to respond to configuration changes while keeping running. There are common patterns that allow you to achieve this. Typically you want to define that application's component object graph once. Although you might create such graph per request, in my experience, it's better to ensure the shape of the graph doesn't change later on. Instead, you can use patterns such as [Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) and [Composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). For instance considering the following interface and implementations:

```cs
interface INotificationSender
{
    void Send(string message);
}

class MailNotificationSender : INotificationSender { ... }

class SmsNotificationSender : INotificationSender { ... }
```

We can define a Proxy as follows:

```cs
class ConfigBasedNotificationSenderProxy : INotificationSender
{
    private readonly INotificationSender mail;
    private readonly INotificationSender sms;

    public ConfigBasedNotificationSenderProxy(
        INotificationSender mail, INotificationSender sms)
    {
        this.mail = mail;
        this.sms = sms;
    }

    public void Send(string message) => GetConfiguredSender().Send(message);

    private INotificationSender GetConfiguredSender()
    {
        bool sendThroughMail = ReadFromConfgWhereToSendTo();
        return sendThroughMail ? this.mail : this.sms;
    }
}
```

You can build the following object graph at application startup:

```cs
var sender =
    new ConfigBasedNotificationSenderProxy(
        mail: new MailNotificationSender(...)
        sms: new SmsNotificationSender(...));
```

You can wire this with a DI Container as well, using a 'DI code generator', or do it by hand (Pure DI) as the previous snippet shows. Wiring this using Pure DI is trivial, while your millage might vary depending on the tool you use.

Important point however that I'm trying to make here is, that even if you need to change how the application behaves **at runtime**, you don't need to rewire your application. You should be able to change the call graph that goes through the application's object graphs by using Proxy implementations.

This is different to the ability to change the configuration only at startup. In that case the composition of your object graphs can be as follows:

```cs
var config = ReadConfigurationFile();
INotificationSender sender = config["mail"] == "true"
    ? new MailNotificationSender(...)
    ? new SmsNotificationSender(...));

var consumer = new SomeConsumer(sender);
```

In this case, the `ConfigBasedNotificationSenderProxy` isn't required, because only one implementation will be used while the application is running. Changing how notification are sent, in this case, means changing the configuration file and, therefore, restarting the application. I have too little experience with 'DI code generators' to describe how they would handle this last scenario.

Comment: Updated with information about changing application behavior at runtime.

Comment: "DI Containers by definition work by using reflection which means runtime metadata"
The likes of Dagger and Micronaut would like a word.