# Switching of dependency injection bindings at startup based on input - good or bad practice?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, console-application, .net-core

I'm writing a console application for .Net Core, and using the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection package.

The console app will take switches at the command line which will change its behaviour, but the intent remains the same each time:

- Take data from a database,
- massage said data into a common format,
- output some kind of report,
- and send it to some destination.

I'm considering doing something like this:

```
string actionSwitch = "a"; // this would come from the command line

var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

switch (actionSwitch)
{
    case "a": // set up bindings for application mode a
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IDatabaseReaderService, ReadFromMySqlService>();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IReportGeneratorService, HtmlReportGeneratorService>();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IReportOutputService, OutputReportToDiskService>();
        break;

    case "b": // set up bindings for application mode b
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IDatabaseReaderService, ReadFromXmlFileService>();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IReportGeneratorService, PdfReportGeneratorService>();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IReportOutputService, OutputReportToFtpService>();
        break;
}

serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IReportProcessService, ReportProcessService>();

var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

var process = serviceProvider.GetService<IReportProcessService>();

process.Execute();
```

ie. the bindings are configured based on the user's input at the command line.

Having only recently started to use DI, all the examples I've seen follow the same pattern:

1. Declare the bindings in a Startup or Initialisation class.
2. Leave them alone forever after.

Does the above code represent reasonable use of DI, or is it bad practice to use application logic to select bindings at startup?

Comment: @Steven - many thanks for an informative answer and useful reading links! Have edited the title for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question title is a bit misleading. When we talk about 'runtime' in the context of DI, we are typically referring to everything that happens *after* the bindings have been configured. What you are doing is not to be considered to be *runtime*, but rather *startup-time* or *configuration-time* (not to confuse with compile-time btw).

Whether decisions on how to wire your dependencies comes from a config file, command line argument or a database is irrelevant here. As long as they are all *constants* that are known at *startup-time*, what you're doing is completely fine, sane and actually *is* a good practice.

Things change however when you are actually trying to change your bindings *at runtime*, i.e. changing the container **while the application is running**. That would be considered to be a bad practice.

There are many reasons for this to be bad practice, and lots has been written about this, such as [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) and [here](https://simpleinjector.org/locked) and this is the main reason why most DI Containers in the .NET space are now moving into an immutable model ([1](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2017/03/01/autofac-conditional-registration-support/), [2](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/IReadOnlyKernel.cs), [3](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/)).

In case different components need to be called due to variables that actually change during runtime (opposed to values that are constant after startup), the advice is to use adapter and proxy classes that hide the fact that dispatching takes place at runtime. For an example, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43801775/264697).

TLDR;

- Changing bindings during the application's lifetime: **bad**.
- Configuring the container up-front once: **good**.
- Using proxies and adapters to change components being used at runtime: **good**.